# can we always find an element that is the minimum element in its row and is the maximum element in its column?

Tags: matrices, number-theory

Given a matrix, can we always find an element that is the minimum element in its row and is the maximum element in its column? If we can, why is that true?

Comment: Consider $[3, 1; 2,4]$ as a $2$ by $2$ matrix... or the identity matrix for a larger example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, consider the matrix:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}1&2\\2&1\end{matrix}\right)$$

The minimum elements in each row are 1, but neither of them are maximal in their respective columns.